# How to build files for two HTML pages using Vue?

Tags: html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-cli-4

Right now, I have two HTML files I want to build. My project structure is like so.

```
|- node_modules
|- public
|  |- blog
|  |  |- some-page.html
|  |- index.html
|- src (contains all the Vue components)
   |- Blog.Vue
   |- Index.Vue
   |- main.js
```

In my `some-page.html`, I have a `div` with the ID `blog` and in my `index.html` file, I have a `div` with the ID `app`. Then, in my `main.js`, I have this code.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Index from './Index.vue';
import Blog from './Blog.vue';
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: (h) => h(Index),
}).$mount('#app');

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  render: (h) => h(Blog),
}).$mount('#blog');
```

When I build the project, the `some-page.html` doesn't get updated at all. The `index.html` page works fine. How can I make it so when I build the project, the `some-page.html` is also injected with the Vue component? I want to upload the built files to my server for hosting for my personal experimentation of using Vue.

I have the source code published on Github here: https://github.com/171112542/seo

Comment: In my experience with Vue 2 and the Vue CLI, I haven't seen two Vue instances in main.js.  I recommend using only one, usually used for rendering App.vue, and the other SFCs can be descendants (child, etc.) of App.vue. Convert some-page.html into the template of an SFC.

Comment: @Tim I'm trying to make two different pages instead of using one page that refreshes its content. (Non-SPA)

Comment: I recommend using Vue the way it's described and exampled in the documentation and tutorials, redesigning your application to fit that structure.  Obviously up to you.  Maybe someone else will have done what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using Vue CLI, you can use it's "multi-page mode" configurable with the [pages](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#pages) config

Note that each `html` template should have it's own separate `main.js` entry point